# Avoiding linebreak before environment adjustwidth

Tags: adjustwidth

In the MWE, after the arrow the line is empty and the text starts in a new line.
Can I achieve that the text starts after the arrow? Neither ~ nor \nolinebreak do not work. The arrow should be where it is in the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newenvironment{myenvironment}
{\noindent$\rightarrow$\begin{adjustwidth}{3em}{0em}}
{\end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{document}
\noindent Hello.
\begin{myenvironment}
\blindtext
\end{myenvironment}
\end{document}
```

Comment: adjustwidth is a display environment, like center, you can't put anything to the left of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the elements as part of the `adjustwidth` environment contents rather than before it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage}

\newenvironment{myenvironment}
  {\begin{adjustwidth}{3em}{0em}
   \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[3em][l]{$\rightarrow$}}\ignorespaces}
  {\end{adjustwidth}}

\begin{document}

\noindent Hello.
\begin{myenvironment}
\blindtext
\end{myenvironment}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But then the arrow is also indented, but it should be were it is in the MWE.

Comment: @Thales: That wasn't clear from the question. I've updated my answer to hopefully reflect what you're after.